# Using pug to generate raw text

Tags: typescript, pug

Is it possible to use or configure [pug](https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html) to generate raw text instead of html ?

I would like the following code line to generate

> Hello John Doe

instead of

> `<Hello>John Doe</Hello>`

```
render("Hello #{name}", { name: "John Doe" }))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to prefix the line with a pipe (`|`). See [here](https://pugjs.org/language/plain-text.html) for more documentation on plain text rendering with Pug.